# Android Local Storage-(No database)

Tags: android

what does it mean when I am asked to use local storage for storing employee details in android and if I used internal file storage for saving the details then is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Welcome to Sack Overflow. Please consider reading stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to better detail your issue to the community

Answer (score 0):

There are many types of storage available to the app.

Database, Shared preferences, Cache, App Storage and phone storage.

What are you trying to save? What is your data? What is its structure? Is it big or small? Does it stay even after the app is removed?

Most of the time you want to keep your storage away from the phone's storage since that is a very dangerous permission to ask the user. But if you're planning on saving json files, use either Shared preferences to save it in string form, or save the file in the app's cache storage.